# How to access data from a database with sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a database that stores data on different players of my game and need to be able to fetch that data. This is the function I have to fetch the data turn it to a list and display it:

```
    def select_all_tasks(self):
        # Get the data from Player Table
        self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM PLAYER")
        rows = self.c.fetchall()

        # Change data from tuple to list
        rows = [list(row) for row in rows]

        for row in rows:
            print(row)
```

I want to be able to assess the data and store it in variables but when I try to assess it like this:

```
print(rows[1]) / print(rows[1][1])
```

I get the output of:

```
None
```

My expected output should be:

```
[x,x,x,x,...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call unnecessary `list` method on every element in below line:

```
rows = [list(row) for row in rows]
```

Replace the above with:

```
rows = [row for row in rows]
```

This will convert tuples into a list.

#### Also make sure that your function returns `rows` to access it.

```
def select_all_tasks(self):
    .....
    .....
    rows = self.c.fetchall()
    return rows
```

Check below example of how you can access it:

```
In [514]: tuple_of_tuples = ((1, 2), (2, 3))                                                                                                                                                                

In [515]: tuple_of_tuples                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[515]: ((1, 2), (2, 3))

In [516]: list_of_tuples = [row for row in tuple_of_tuples]                                                                                                                                                 

In [517]: list_of_tuples                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[517]: [(1, 2), (2, 3)]

In [518]: list_of_tuples[0]                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[518]: (1, 2)

In [519]: list_of_tuples[0][0]                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[519]: 1

In [520]: list_of_tuples[0][1]                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[520]: 2
```